# Custom Sorting in Gridview

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, sorting, gridview

I need to implement sorting in gridview with an additional row added below columns that would be having the sorting images (ascending & descending). The sorting functionality is obvious and need no explanation.

I have added a empty datarow to the datatable which makes a room for row as mentioned.

My Question: How to add the images into the empty datarow? (and perform sorting)

Some information:

1. .net version: .net 3.5 , Visual Studio 2008
2. My GV is NOT binded to any datasource. It is binded to simple data-table-column-row.

Please guide me!

Comment: "The functionality is obvious and need no explanation." This is incorrect.

Comment: By that i mean for the sort feature (asc/desc). How the sorting works is very common

Comment: Dude, I can't even understand what you *want*...

Comment: i wish to add image button control in empty data row in GV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question in a way that you want to add images to header that indicate the current sort direction (asc/desc). For this, don't add an extra data row, but instead add image to the column `HeaderTemplate`.
This can be done in `RowCreated` event, as described in third comment [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/17/10254863/gridview-sorting-headertemplate.aspx).